# How to use Boost library in C++ with Rcpp

Tags: c++, boost, rcpp

I am using **Rcpp** package on **R 3.0.0**. I am trying to run [**this example**](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/a-first-boost-example/), but I cannot because I don't know how to use **Boost**.

I installed Boost in the directory /Users/giorgi/boost_1_53_0 therefore I set `Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-I /Users/giorgi/boost_1_53_0")` but I am not sure I am doing the right thing. Sorry but I am quite ignorant with this stuff!

Comment: Do you get a specific error when compiling, what is not working?

Answer (score 16):

I would try a few things:

1. Write a three line standalone C++ program using Boost, and compile it. This is just to prove to yourself that you have the `-I/some/dir` flag right.
2. Write a simple Rcpp function and use eg `sourceCpp()` to compile and load it.
3. Create a file `~/.R/Makevars` and set the `-I` flag from 1. here as either one one of `CXXFLAGS` or `CFLAGS` both of which will be used by `R CMD ...` and hence `sourceCpp()`.
4. If everything else fails, create a small package and add `LinkingTo: BH` as the CRAN package BH provides Boost headers you can use (once you install BH).

*Edit, about 1 1/2 years later*

You can also use a `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` as eg in this code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/math/common_factor.hpp>  // included in BH  

// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]    

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]   
int computeGCD(int a, int b) {
  return boost::math::gcd(a, b);
}
```

which builds and runs just fine as we updated both Rcpp and BH in the meantime:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/simpleBoost.cpp")
R> computeGCD(6, 15)
[1] 3
R>
```