# Problems with Boost and Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to use Boost together with Rcpp as in [this example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/a-first-boost-example/) by Dirk Eddelbuettel. I cannot, however, compile this example as I get

```
"fatal error: 'boost/math/common_factor.hpp' file not found".
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131462/how-to-use-boost-library-in-c-with-rcpp) question and done item 1 and 2 in the list of suggestions by Dirk. Especially, when doing 1 it seems that I can build a C++ program utilizing the boost library. Furthermore, on my MacBook it seems like Boost is located in the directory `/opt/local/include/`.

Regarding number 3 in the list of suggestions it is not clear to me what exactly to put in the makevars file though. Any Ideas?

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost/math/common_factor.hpp` does not seem to be part of BH, so item 4 can be ruled out. If you have boost headers installed in `/opt/local/include`, for item 3, you can do something like this perhaps:

```
 PKG_CXXFLAGS += -I/opt/local/include
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work. I had previously tried PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I  /opt/local/include/. What is the difference? Also, I am actually  interested in sampling from the inverse gamma and the truncated normal distribution. As they are not standard in R they seem to be unavailable when using Rcpp. This is where Boost comes in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have difficulties instructing the compiler to find a complete Boost installation, you could always switch to another example from the Rcpp Gallery as eg

- [this post about using Boost via the BH package](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-boost-with-bh/), or
- [this post about Boost FOREACH](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-foreach/)

both of which should work with a `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]`.