# Rcpp and Boost Multiprecision,

Tags: r, boost, rcpp, boost-multiprecision

I want to use boost/multiprecision with Rcpp. Therefore I looked around and found these threads about boost: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262963/rcpp-with-quad-precision-computation) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131462/how-to-use-boost-library-in-c-with-rcpp). The first one about quad-precision is exactly what I want to use. The problem is that I cannot compile the given example. However, I can compile the example from the second thread which just uses a different directory in the boost package. So I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong. Relevant code from the first thread:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string qexp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0)
{
    mp::float128 a(da), b(db);
    mp::float128 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
    return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string mpfr_exp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0)
{
    mp::mpf_float_100 a(da), b(db);
    mp::mpf_float_100 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
    return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}
```

The error I get is: ".../R/win-library/3.3/BH/include/boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp:21:17: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include ". But when I browse to: ".../R/win-library/3.3/BH/include/boost/multiprecision/" the file "gmp.hpp" is there. I already tried running "Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-lmpfr -lgmp")" as described in the first thread, but no luck. Any suggestions? In case it matters, I'm using windows.

Comment: What version of BH are you using?

Comment: I'm using BH_1.62.0-1.

Comment: You will need to install the [GMP library](http://cs.nyu.edu/~exact/core/gmp/index.html) (most likely the MinGW variant). The issue cited is not with the file `boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp`, but the fact that this header contains `#include <gmp.h>`. `boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp` is just a sort of wrapper around the core GMP library, so you will still need `<gmp.h>` on your system to use the Boost classes that provide GMP functionality.

Comment: Okay, luckily I already did that. Then how do I tell R where it is? (I installed it in "C:\c++\gmp\gmp-6.1.2"). The "gmp.h" file is present in the main folder.

Comment: Try running `Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS" = "-IC:\c++\gmp\gmp-6.1.2")` (or whichever directory `gmp.h` is located in) before compiling.

Comment: @nrussell is too modest as he _just_ created a tutorial for this [over at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42307240/143305).

Comment: So I tried `Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS" = "-IC:/c++/gmp/gmp-6.1.2")` but now I get the error `#include <mpfr.h>` not found. I guess I'll have to install GNU MPFR first and then add that to PKG_CPPFLAGS in the same way?